# MySQL - Filter one last item

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the different majors involved in various program courses. I have it mostly done, but noticed that I am counting duplicate usernames if they are registered for more than one course. Can you help me get the DISTINCT tag somewhere in this query?

```
SELECT a.`major_desc` AS `major`, 
(SELECT COUNT(a.`major_desc`) FROM all_students WHERE major_desc=`major` LIMIT 1) AS `count` 
FROM all_students AS a 
INNER JOIN all_course_reg AS b ON a.username=b.username 
INNER JOIN courses AS c ON b.`crn`=c.`crn` 
GROUP BY `major`
```

EDIT: sqlfiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81bb0/3/0

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry, thank you for letting me know what to do. Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81bb0/3/0

Comment: As you'll see in the sqlfiddle above, I'm getting a count of 3 for major1 (all 3 from Jim Halpert) while I would like to further filter it and only count jim one time.

Comment: Please amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go. Thanks to my boy 3mHz.

```
SELECT a.major_desc, 
   (select count(a.username)) as test
FROM all_students AS a 
WHERE EXISTS (select * from all_course_reg
    inner join courses on courses.crn=all_course_reg.crn
    where all_course_reg.username=a.username)
GROUP BY a.major_desc
```

So we now get the right count for each major if the course is offered within the set of program courses.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is what you're after - I don't know what all that other stuff is for...

```
SELECT major_desc, COUNT(*) cnt  
  FROM all_students
 GROUP
    BY major_desc;
```